# Cannot make command line tool for artisan in PhpStorm 2017.1.3

Tags: laravel, symfony, phpstorm

I got this error message when I tried to make an alias for `artisan: [Settings | Tools | Command Line Tool Support ] -> add -> tool` based on `Symfony Console`.

Problem:

> Failed to parse output as xml: Error on line 3: Content is not allowed
>   in prolog..

Command:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\artisan list --format=xml
```

Output:

```
 [Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException]
```

Even when I try `artisan serve` or `composer install`,
then  `[Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException]` bug is occured.

I don't find any solution for this.

I'm using Laravel 5.2 + Angular 1.

Comment: 1) Works fine for Laravel 5.4.23 (using `Tool based on Symfony Console`). 2) *"Even when I try artisan serve or composer install"* This could mean that composer installation/json could be somehow broken ... or PHP itself is missing some stuff (e.g. required extension). I may suggest to check first if your PHP has all required extensions for Laravel enabled. Then try `composer validate` -- maybe it will show something. If still the same check PHP's error log.

Answer (score 0):

I had recently issues running artisan commands (ide-helper for example) directly in phpstorm, I'd recommend you to use your OS terminal instead. It might help you.